# Why direct call on object do not has default methods?

Tags: javascript

So, there is a code:

`({}).toString() // "[object Object]"`

And this fails:

`{}.toString() // Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '.'`

Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`{}` isn't an object. It's a [block](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/block). The `{` and `}` have different meanings in JS depending on the context they are used in.